# AngularJS $timeout inactive when tab switched

Tags: angularjs, settimeout

I have a functionality of timer in my Application. A user can start a timer to measure the time taken to complete a particular task. I keep the start time and end time at the backend so I get the total time. But I need to display the time elapsed to the user. I use the `$timeout` function to call a function every second to display time.

```
function displayTime(){
               time = time + 1;
               var hours,minutes,seconds;
               hours = parseInt((time/3600)%24);
               minutes = parseInt((time/60)%60);
               seconds = time%60;
               $scope.timer = hours+ ":"+minutes+":"+seconds;
               t = $timeout(displayTime,1000);
           }
```

But when tab is switched the $timeout function is inactive or slows down and the time displayed slows down considerably. Is there a way to solve this problem? Can I find the exact time when the user switches tabs?

Comment: Try it using $interval. link to document : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the "$interval" service instead of "$timeout".

```
angular.module('myApp',[])
    .controller('exampleCtrl', function($scope, $interval) {

        var timeInterval;

        function startDisplayTime(time) {
            var fnTime = function(t) {
               var hours,minutes,seconds;
               hours = parseInt((t/3600)%24);
               minutes = parseInt((t/60)%60);
               seconds = t%60;
               $scope.timer = hours+ ":"+minutes+":"+seconds; 
            };

            var ntime = time + 1;
            timeInterval = $interval(fnTime(ntime), 10000);
        }

        function stopDisplayTime() {
           $interval.cancel(timeInterval);
        }


        ....


        startDisplayTime(someLogicForGetTime());
    });
```

Comment: It works! What exactly is the difference between $timeout and $setInterval?

Comment: 1) interval : it runs every time.
2) timeout : it runs just one time.